# How can I use data in two columns, along with today’s date, to yield a new piece of information?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 16.21.1

**BACKGROUND and DATA:**

I am a professor with a cumulative master roster of all the students I have taught. I have a column that tells me what year a particular student, e.g. “Bob,” (Row 3) took my class (Col. C = 2015). Another column lists Bob’s year in school (Col. D = third year) at the time he took my class.

**PROCESS AND DESIRED OUTCOME:**

**I am hoping there is a way to create another column (Col. F) that will tell me what year in school a student is now/if a student is likely to still be on campus.**

**I am also hoping that by referring to a cell or column with the TODAY function, the new column will continually update. e.g. For a student who was a first year in Winter 2018, the new column would show the student to be a second year now. Next January, it would show the student to be a third year.**

To do that, Excel will have to:

1. Take the information in Column C – the year Carly took my class – and:

   a. Know that 15W = winter quarter of 2015 = January – March of each year. “15W” is my university’s format, so I need to keep it that way, but define the terms for Excel.

   b. Know that JR = third year in school; SR = fourth year, etc. This is my university’s format, so I need to keep the “FR,” “JR,” etc., but define the terms for Excel.

   c. Assume a four-year track for graduation. To make this easier, I want to assume the most common scenario. So Andy Andrews, who in 17S who was a FR (first year) began school in 16F (fall) and stayed a first year for 16W (winter) and 17S (spring), at which point he became a SO (second year) for 17F, 18W and 18S.

   d. Compare the year Carly was in my class and her year in school when she took my class, with today’s date to give me an estimate of what year she is now or whether she graduated for my new Column F.

   e. i.e. In Spring 2016 (Col. C), Carly was a first year (Col. D). Since it is now Winter 2019, Carly should be in her fourth year and graduating in 19S, Spring of this year.

**# Do I need to create a column that will have the TODAY function in a 
    whole column of cells, all the way down? Just one cell 
    for the formula to refer to? Something else?**

**# It seems clunky to have an entire column of today’s date. Could the function refer to a single cell at the top of the sheet? Ora cell with hidden info?**

2. A complication: I need to tell excel that the terminal point for each year is after the Spring quarter, so that a student’s “year in school” changes after the S (Spring) part of a year. (We could call it July 1, to be on the safe side.) Same thing with graduation – it happens after S (or July 1) so that’s the point after which I need it my sheet to note that the student has graduated.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

[Spreadsheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0AfL.png)

Comment: Does the student year designation always presume entry is from the beginning of the year, or could a student enter in winter and still be a FR the following spring?

Comment: In the first example the person took the class in 17S and was a FR could they have begun school in 16W

Comment: There are many, many possibilities including students who graduate in three years and students who graduate in five. But for my purposes, I'm fine with presuming the year changes happen in the fall and terminate after spring.

Comment: To further make clear, @datatoo, we're going to assume the most common scenario: The person in 17S who was a FR began school in 16F (fall) and stayed a FR for 16W and 17S at which point he/she became a SO.

Comment: @datatoo, I updated the main post to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to tackle these kinds of tasks is with helper columns; you can combine them into a single formula when you're done.  Use them to convert the raw data from your school's coding scheme into values you can calculate from.  You can also use them for intermediate calculations.  Once you have that, the rest should be simple arithmetic.  Just break it down into pieces and figure out the pieces.  You've done a pretty good job of identifying those requirements.  (cont'd)

Comment: The entire task is a bit broad for a single question here, and the site discourages "write me code" kinds of questions (we don't want to turn the site into a free coding service).  In "school terms", do your own homework and ask for help with specific issues.  :-)  People will help you solve specific problems you encounter trying to do this yourself.  Each piece of this puzzle is more in line with the intended scope of a question.